# EEA Family Permit for extended family member

Tags: united-kingdom

I hold a UK residence permit under eu-scheme settlement with pre-settled status as a dependent of my Italian(achieved and origin Bangladesh) Father.  My baby got eu-scheme family permit visa as a grand-child and she is less then 2 years old. Problem is my wife applied as a dependent daughter-in-law and got refusal letter. The entry clearance in refusal letter mentioned that he is not satisfied with 6 months money transfer receipts. He asked at least 12 months. And ask for evidence of her expenditure . What should i submit as evidence on re application ?

Comment: I think you need to challenge this.  But you should seek out an immigration lawyer to help you.  Although, this will cost money you will have a much better chance of success than if you just reapply yourself as they can advise you to what exactly you should do to improve your chances.