# Can I apply for UK tourist visa after EEA family permit refusal?

Tags: uk-visa

I applied for my wife for EEA family permit as an extended family member of my EU nation father. however got refusal because of low family income. I want to know can i apply for a UK tourist visa for my wife now ?

Comment: There’s nothing in the UK Immigration Rules to prevent your wife from applying. As for all visit visa applicants, she will need to demonstrate that she meets the eligibility criteria https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules If you are already resident in the UK, the ECO will likely pay close attention to her ability to show she intends to leave at the end of her visit ie her ties to her home country. You may get better answers if you explain more about her circumstances.

Comment: The OP's two previous questions on this same subject (https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20373/dependent-child-can-sponsor-wife-for-uk-family-visa and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20070/eea-family-permit-for-extended-family-member) provide more info. Perhaps they can be combined in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

Your wife can apply for a tourist visa but the application is almost certain to fail.  If you have enough money that this prospect doesn't worry you, then instead of giving your money to the UK, consider hiring an immigration lawyer.